# Jdk version automatically resets to 1.7 in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio and i have both Jdk 1.7 as well as 1.8. When I executed the app , it gave me an error that it needs to be run with Jdk 1.8.I wen to File>> project structure and changed the path for jdk versio to jdk 1.8 but when I click OK the gradle sync starts with jdk 1.7 . Now when I open the project structure again, JDk version is reset to 1.7 again.

My `JAVA_HOME` system variable is set to the jdk 1.8 path. I uninstalled the Android Studio and reinstalled it, but nothing worked.

Comment: Android doesn't support Java 8 (yet).

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle also include the compileOptions tag to force JDK 1.8.

You will need to enable the Jack compiler as well to take advantage of Java 8 features.

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

See Google's page on Java 8 features available on Android here: https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html

Also, keep in mind that certain features are not support under Java 8 with the Jack compiler. One of the biggest (for me at least) is the Transform API with annotation processors. If you or a library you like uses the Transform API, you can disable Jack, and use a library to get some Java 8 features anyway, like Retrolambda.

See here for details on RetroLambda: https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

Comment: I tried this. But then when i run the application, the gradle takes forever to build. the gradle console is stuck at :app:compileDebugJavaWithJack

Comment: and then after 12  minutes i got the error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJack'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: That's Jack for you. It's still in beta, and that's exactly what happened to me when I tried it a couple of months ago. I recommend using a 3rd party library to back port Java 8 features for now, and then switch to Jack when it's primetime.